# Magento Custom Grid delete action not working

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I have Magento custom grid that is showing my list of products I want to remove my product when someone click on delete action. I have written my action code that is below but it is not working everytime when I click on delete it shows me 404 page when using url `(*/*/delete)` and when I changed the url to `(*/*/../../admin/catalog_product/delete)` it will go to dashboard page but didn't delete my product:

```
$this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => 'Action',
                'width'     => '100px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Any solution for my this problem will really helpfull for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is on url making,try to make url as follow in actions.

Note : Replace param_id as per your url perameter and module name as per your module name in helper.

```
 'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('module_name')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'     => array(
                        'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                        'params'=> array('id'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('param_id'))
                        ),'field'   => 'id'
                        ),

                        array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('module_name')->__('Delete'),
                        'url'     => array(
                        'base'=>'*/*/delete',
                        'params'=> array('id'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('param_id'))
                        ),'field'   => 'id'
                        )

                        ),
```

Comment: I am doing like this getParam('*/*/../../admin/catalog_product/delete')
this also not working or I am doing wrong something.

Comment: Hi Andrew in getParam you have to define primary key of your module that will help to identify which record you want to delete. so try  like 'params'=> array('id'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('primary_key')). Follow actions as above that i have define i am sure that will work for you.

Comment: After defining above code make sure you have deleteAction() method defined in your admin side controller of your module.

Comment: Thanks... It works without using params... I only need to define deleteaction() in controller

Comment: @AndrewHall : If you find the answer helpful then do consider upvoting or accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created a delete action, try modify the above code to:

```
$this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => 'Action',
                'width'     => '100px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/delete'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
                )
```

Comment: This is not working... When I click it a blank page opened... where as product is also not deleted